# Java util ConcurrentException: ProcessException in android

Tags: java, android, gradle, java.util.concurrent, android-debug

I am getting frustrated. Everything was fine in my project. Then i wanted to implement google custom tab and added dependency. But as soon as I sync the project it is showing the error. I tried to remove the dependency but still the problem is occurring. I have searched in google and stackoverflow. All i got is about `multiDex`. I have added that too but nothing is changed.
The error and stack trace:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
```

The dependency code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "razon.tasktodo"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://dl.bintray.com/gigamole/maven/'
    }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
compile 'com.github.halysongoncalves:pugnotification:1.8.1'
compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.3.1'
compile 'com.github.devlight.navigationtabstrip:navigationtabstrip:+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.5'
compile 'com.github.armcha:SpaceNavigationView:1.5.0'
compile 'com.github.devlight:infinitecycleviewpager:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'

}
```

Please help me to get rid of it.

Comment: did you tried `gradle clean` after removing dependency ??

Comment: I have tried clean and rebuild several time. I have even tried invalidate and cache restart too. What is gradle clean?

Comment: Post full Logcat message to have a clear inspection.